# Cypress: Webpack Compilation Error

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, node.js, npm, cypress

I am new to cypress and I have installed Cypress on my ubuntu 22.04 PC and when I try to run the test case, I was getting the following error message:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module build failed (from ../../.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
Require stack:
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/cross_origin.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_require_async_child.js
- /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/require_async_child.js
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:212:23)
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:303:9
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Watching._done (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:299:28)
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:213:21
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:919:5)
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:191:22
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:885:14
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:882:27
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at alreadyWritten (/home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:714:8)
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:802:19
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at /home/user1213/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
```

The test case which I executed was the default test case which was already available in the cypress `todo.cy.js`

Here are my cypress environment details:

```
Cypress package version: 13.6.6
Cypress binary version: 13.6.6
Electron version: 27.1.3
Bundled Node version: 18.17.1
```

Node js version:`v12.22.9`
NPM version:`8.5.1`

Can someone please help me here to how can I fix this issue please.

Comment: Did you [google the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A+Cannot+find+module+'fs%2Fpromises')? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085375/cannot-find-module-fs-promises-electron-js

Comment: NodeJS 12 has been out of support for almost two years now. It is time to upgrade.

Comment: Hello @Gantendo, Thanks for your response. Yeah, I have googled and tried the solutions mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085375/cannot-find-module-fs-promises-electron-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085375/cannot-find-module-fs-promises-electron-js) but it dint solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielB, after updating the nodejs problem got solved. I was trying to update the nodejs via terminal command and its always installing the nodejs 12, So I tried via download and install the latest nodejs then it worked, and issue got fixed, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Izaz if you've tried things already, please list the things you've tried so we know what not to suggest.